# Is it possible to use DMEE tree for import and parsing xml file

Tags: xml, import, xml-parsing, abap, sap-erp

I need to develop import of xml files with quite complicated structure into SAP.
Earlier I used DMEE format trees for export xml and it was quite easy and flexibly. And since this is called "Data Medium **Exchange** Engine", so I thought that this could be used in both directions, that is, for import too. But I can't find any docs or examples of how to do it.

I've read the topic
[Parsing XML within SAP ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765936/parsing-xml-within-sap-abap)
but before I follow it I just want to be sure that DMEE is really useless for import.

Comment: See my answer, DMEE does have an upload XML function. See include LDMEE1_ABAF50

Comment: @forgetaboutme Form xml_upload_format is used only in FM DMEE_UPLOAD_XML_TREE_ABA. I've explored the FM and it is for uploading format tree only. You can't use it for importing and parsing your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iXML library to import and parse your xml file.

As mentioned in the help page:

> When XML data is saved in strings or internal tables, it is best to
>   use byte strings or byte-like row types and the UTF-8 code page for
>   the representation.

Therefore, if manipulating byte strings, you can use the [`CALL TRANSFORMATION`](https://ldai4uia.wdf.sap.corp:44300/sap/public/bc/abap/docu?input=CALL%20TRANSFORMATION&format=standard&object=abapcall_transformation&sap-language=EN&sap-client=000&tree=X) statement to convert your XML to ABAP:

```
call transformation id
  source xml i_xml_string
  result ...
```

The [`CALL TRANSFORMATION`](https://ldai4uia.wdf.sap.corp:44300/sap/public/bc/abap/docu?input=CALL%20TRANSFORMATION&format=standard&object=abapcall_transformation&sap-language=EN&sap-client=000&tree=X) help page has a lot of examples. You can also find more info on the following [SAP help portal](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_xml_libs.htm).

DMEE does have an upload XML function. It uses the iXML library - see include `LDMEE1_ABAF50`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but still I'm curious if it is possible to do import thru DMEE.